# MVC pattern : best way to display an array of elements

Tags: c#, java, model-view-controller, frameworks

Suppose I have this div on the `view` section :

```
<div class='my class'>
    <%=myVariableToPrint %>
</div>
```

There isnt problems there : I just take from my class/bean (`model`) my data and put it on a div.

Now, suppose that myVariableToPrint is an array of 10 strings, and I need to print the div 10 times, each div for each string on the array. How can I do it?

Put the div on the model like :

```
myString+="<div class='my class'>"+myVariable[i]+"</div>"
```

and print `myString` on the `view` section it's noisy :)

Any solutions?

P.s. I'm speaking about C# there, but should be the same on Java ecc

Comment: I wouldn't add any HTML in the model. Say you have a different view that depends on the same data? Than the HTML might be different. Printing the array is simply view logic, so there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I updated my answer to show another solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `<div>` inside the loop

```
<% foreach (var item in myArray) { %>
    <div class='my class'>
        <%= item %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

**Update** 
Ok, from your comments it looks like you don't want any loop logic in your views. Really you shouldn't worry about that. Views have that kind of stuff in. It might look a bit messy but it is generally the correct way to do things. Putting html in your model just so that you can render it is **definitely a really bad idea**. Please don't do that.

One other way you could do it would be with a custom `Html.Helper` method.You could do something like....

```
public static string DivList(this HtmlHelper helper, IList<string> list, string divClass)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(string item in list)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"{0}\">{1}</div>", divClass, item); 
    }     
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And you can use this in the view like...

```
<%= Html.DivList(Model.MyList, "myClass") %>
```

which is a lot neater.

Comment: why? who says he is rendering user input? and anyway, i've just used his original snippet to show the answer. it's a question about how to do a loop in a view, not how to encode user input.

Comment: Yeah, but having many model elements (for each, if, ecc) on the view is not so well :) @SLaks♦ : Why XSS hole?

Comment: @mark: Because it's not escaped.  What if the string has `<script>` in it?

Comment: That's not means with my question. Of course the strings must be escaped :)

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate the collection using a `foreach` loop and put your HTML inside the loop.

Using Razor (because it's easier):

```
@foreach(string s in something {
    <div class="Something">@s</div>
}
```

Comment: I'd like to have only html elements (and variables from model) in the view section...that's why I opened this question :)

Comment: That is very wrong.  The model **should not** contain any view logic, such as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Put the collection in the model.

The view iterates over the collection to create the final output.

Comment: Can you give to me an example?